# The exact same code from a tutorial that keeps giving me syntax errors

Tags: javascript, node.js

So... this is the exact same code from a youtube tutorial and when he typed this code and ran it, he didn't get a single error but when I did it, I got 2 errors which are ';' expected and ',' expected.
The link to the original code on the tutorial: https://youtu.be/IgAH0NqsJso?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9gcy9lrvMJ75z9maRw4byYp&t=58

```
module.exports = funciton(app) {

    app.get('/todo', function(req, res) {
        res.render('todo');

    });



    app.post('/todo', funciton(req, res) {


    });
    app.delete('/todo:item', function(req, res) {


    });

}
```

Comment: You mispelled function `funciton` is that a typo in writing the question or an actual typo in your code

Comment: actual typos.... I just realized that ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct one. Please watch the video more carefully. Also, follow the error messages. There is the line number in error message. Just check the line number and find what went wrong. :)

```
module.exports = function(app) { // misspelled the word 'function'

    app.get('/todo', function(req, res) {
        res.render('todo');

    });



    app.post('/todo', function(req, res) { // misspelled the word 'function'


    });
    app.delete('/todo/:item', function(req, res) { // Missed "/" in the end point


    });

}
```

Comment: I totally missed those typos. Thanks.

Comment: Typo questions should not be answered, there are close votes for closing such questions